# Ways to improve Vue JSX support

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsx

While using JSX in vue we have to create some dedicated file while in React we could use it on inline JS. Is there a way to reproduce it using vue ?

content of .babelrc :

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

content of vite.config.js:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

Actually i've tried the default configuration using this vue file :

```
<template>
  t
</template>
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'
let t = <div>test</div>
</script>
```

But got this error : [plugin:vite:vue] [vue/compiler-sfc] This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): "jsx", "flow", "typescript". (3:8)

Comment: `@babel/preset-react` is a mistake, JSX shouldn't be converted to React.createElement() at all. Did you try <script setup lang="jsx">?

Comment: yep right now its working but i had to do a couple of changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone has the same problem changes to be done :

App.vue :

```
<template>
  <t></t>
</template>
<script setup lang="jsx">
import {ref} from 'vue'
let t = <div>test</div>
</script>
```

For the config files, it is ok on the question

Thanks @Estus Flask